# MediaWiki with SQLite: Where are pages stored?

Tags: mediawiki, sqlite, dump

Where does `mediawiki-1.20.2` with `SQLite 3.7.13` store the content of pages? I want to dump the markdown code. I want to get all pages as shown when the "edit" button has been hit.

The `maintenance/sqlite.php --backup-to` script does not work.

`SELECT page_title FROM page;` only queries page titles.

These are the relations:

```
 sqlite> .tables
 archive               module_deps           searchindex_segdir  
 category              msg_resource          searchindex_segments
 categorylinks         msg_resource_links    site_identifiers    
 change_tag            objectcache           site_stats          
 external_user         oldimage              sites               
 externallinks         page                  tag_summary         
 filearchive           page_props            templatelinks       
 hitcounter            page_restrictions     text                
 image                 pagelinks             transcache          
 imagelinks            protected_titles      updatelog           
 interwiki             querycache            uploadstash         
 ipblocks              querycache_info       user                
 iwlinks               querycachetwo         user_former_groups  
 job                   recentchanges         user_groups         
 l10n_cache            redirect              user_newtalk        
 langlinks             revision              user_properties     
 log_search            searchindex           valid_tag           
 logging               searchindex_content   watchlist           
 sqlite>
```

I did not run any DDL or DML statements, except for selects.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT page_title FROM page;` will only return the `page_title` column from the `pages` table. What happens when you `SELECT * FROM page;`? Alternatively, run `.SCHEMA page` to see the structure of the table.

Comment: From a reader's not a DBA's perspective, `SELECT page_title FROM page;` returns list of page titles and IDs. So to say, no content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of pages is stored in [the `text` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table). To get there from `page`, you will need to go through [`revision`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Revision_table). The SQL query could look something like:

```sql
SELECT page_title, old_text
FROM page
JOIN revision ON page_latest = rev_id
JOIN text ON rev_text_id = old_id
```

Comment: First, I did pepare a dump: `sqlite> .mode csv` - `sqlite> .header on` - `sqlite> .out File.csv.txt`. Then, I did run the query as given. Now I have a text file containing all page names followed by page content, in unmodified markdown. Definitely readable.

Comment: This is what I used before, but the database structure is different now. I added a separate answer for current Mediawiki versions.

Answer (score 0):

To export Mediawiki pages as plain text, the query in [svick's answer](https://superuser.com/a/827230/53547) used to work well before version 1.31.

Since then, with the introduction of [Multi-Content-Revisions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Multi-Content_Revisions/Content_Meta-Data), the structure has changed and the id of the current text of a page can be found in the `content_address` field of the [`content` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Content_table).

This is what I use now, with Mediawiki 1.35 and a PostgreSQL database:

```sql
SELECT page_title, page_touched, old_text
FROM page
JOIN slots       ON page.page_latest       = slots.slot_revision_id
JOIN "content"   ON slots.slot_content_id  = content.content_id
JOIN pagecontent ON old_id = REGEXP_REPLACE(content.content_address, '^\D*','')::INTEGER
WHERE page_namespace = 0
```

For SQLite or MySQL, the table `pagecontent` is named `text`, and the `regexp_replace` function would probably need to be adapted.